# How to convert zxcvbn entropy to score

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, password-policy, entropy

I want to use [zxcvbn-c](https://github.com/tsyrogit/zxcvbn-c) but it gives the entropy number, not score like the javascript library does. How do I convert entropy number to a score? (0 to 4)

The zxcvbn [blog](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/)/[source](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) mentions that the score is related to estimated cracktime. I think this will be relative and increasing over time as computers get more powerful. But whats the current recomended formula to convert entropy to cracktime? How can I calculate a score for now? When should I reevaluate?

Heres what I found but how to know what guesses is made from and how to make the formula?

```
0 = guesses < 10^3
1 = guesses < 10^6
2 = guesses < 10^8
3 = guesses < 10^10
4 = guesses >= 10^10
```

IOW **what are recomended entropy gradients for password strength nowadays?**

Comment: Each bit of entropy doubles the expected number of guesses an attacker will have to make, so without looking into it further I would assume you could compare `e < log2(10^n)` where `n` is 3, 6, 8, 10, etc.

Comment: The app also give a "log10" number which is really just entropy * 0.301029996

Comment: Then compare entropy log10 against 3, 6, 8, 10. Same thing either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @AndrolGenhald I think this is how the javascript works

```
log = e * 0.301029996;
if (log < 3) s = 0;
if (log < 6) s = 1;
if (log < 8) s = 2;
if (log < 10) s = 3;
if (log >= 10) s = 4;
```

Should someone have better indepth answer about entropy I will be eager to read it.

Comment: If you want to read up on password entropy in general [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/174744/151903) is a good starting point, and [the xkcd 936 analysis](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6096/151903) is interesting.